# Attempting to use custom facade results in 'Call to undefined method' on Application::create() in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-facade

I am attempting to create my own custom facade for a Search feature, but I'm having a little difficulty:

```
type: Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException
message: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Foundation\Application::create()
file: H:\myproj\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php
line: 165
```

This error is caused by my code hitting:

```
Search::indexObject();
```

Where my `Search` facade is set up as follows:

#### SearchServiceProvider

```
<?php
namespace MyProj\Search;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class SearchServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {

    public function register() {
        $this->app->bind('search', 'MyProj\Search\Search');
    }

}
```

#### Search Facade

```
<?php
namespace MyProj\Facades;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade;

class Search extends Facade {
    public static function getFacadeAccessor() {
        return 'search';
    }
}
```

#### Search class

```
<?php
namespace MyProj\Search;

use Elasticsearch\Client;
use Credential;

class Search {
    private $elasticSearchClient;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->elasticSearchClient = new Client(array(
            'hosts' => [Credential::ElasticSearchHost]
        ));
    }

    public function indexObject($object) {
        // Code 
        return $this->elasticSearchClient->index($params);
    }

    public function get() {
        return $this->$elasticSearchClient;
    }
}
```

I have run `composer dump-autoload` without success, and my facade and service provider is loaded in `app.php` as follows:

#### Aliases array

```
'Search'            => 'MyProj\Facades\Search',
```

#### Providers array

```
'MyProj\Search\SearchServiceProvider'
```

I've spent the past 30 minutes debugging and searching for this error without any fix. What's going on here?

EDIT: I've added in the stack trace, which you can see below. Additionally, I can see that `getFacadeAccessor()` is being called correctly, but anything beyond that is outside of my understanding.

[image]

The highlighted frame represents the last occurrence of normal operation, both frames on `Handler.php` represent the formatting and outputting of the error at the top of the question.

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using? Could you paste a few more lines of the stack trace?

Comment: I guess you're using Laravel 4.2. Did you do any changes to the Laravel code? In line 163 I can see "$method = ($abstract == $concrete) ? 'build' : 'make';", so I see no way how "create()" could be called.

Comment: Did you change the code? Could you paste some more lines of the stack trace?

Comment: Nope, not as far as I'm aware. I've added in the stack trace so you can see what's going on. Let me know if I can provide more info.

Answer (score 3):

Appreciate this is a bit of an old thread, however you'd get the problems described if you compiled cache wasn't cleared after adding your new Facade.

You should run:

`php artisan clear-compiled`